# VS Code (Visual Studio Code) settings.json deployment

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-code

I need to deploy a custom VS Code install to a number of machines. What is the easiest way? I can see hwo to configure things as a user, but would like to deploy it so all users get a set of custom settings (mainly switching telemetry off).

I can run the install silently, but would then have to copy the default settings file somewhere (I think the documentation only references where the user settings are, not default settings).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369371/what-is-the-location-of-the-default-settings-file-of-vscode) seems to have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the aspect of the question that concerns the location of default settings, I'll repeat the "short" version of the [answer I gave elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734678/2659307):

> The default settings are **hardcoded in the vscode sources**. There is no data file anywhere that collects them all together or which could be readily changed to alter them.

Consequently, you'll have to set up and distribute "user" defaults that describe your desired deployment-wide configuration.  I have no experience or advice regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is not able to running then put

```
"java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
 "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "c:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_202"
```

inside Settings.json under .vscode folder

```
Note - It is depend on which jdk version you are using
```